# How can I get the month interval of a transaction from the last date of it's record to the current date?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, transactions

How can I get the month interval of a transaction from the last date of it's record to the current date?
Let's look at the table below!

```
---------------------------------------
|transaction_dates | transaction_time |
---------------------------------------
|2015-01-02        | 11:00:00         |
|2015-01-03        | 12:00:00         |
|2015-02-05        | 7:00:00          |
|2015-03-05        | 10:00:00         |
|2015-03-05        | 19:00:00         |
|2015-04-05        | 13:00:00         |
---------------------------------------
```

From the current date, August 20, 2015. I don't have any transaction for the month of May,June and July. So by doing some PHP script and SQL, how can I get the months wherein transaction becomes idle to the current date? In the above case, my desired output would be

```
-------------
|months_idle|
-------------
|5           |
|6           |
|7           |
--------------
```

Comment: take a look at Carbon, its a great script to mess with dates. https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon

Comment: Why do you need a separate row for each month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create table with months (1..12) in your DB and select all month > max(MONTH(transaction_dates)) and < MONTH(NOW())